# Unity3d: Error building Player: Append is not supported

Tags: ios, xcode, build, unity-game-engine, playhaven

I receive this error when appending an already-successful build in XCode. What I don't understand is I'm not changing anything when appending, and this error shows up.

I've never used an 'old version of Xcode' as the error implicitly states.

Does anyone know how to get append working on a consistent basis?

This is a very simple project, and I'm using Playhaven and TapForTap SDK's, if that offers any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, XCode upgraded itself without telling me. :(
I rolled back to the version I was using and all is well.

Answer (score -1):

With no code snippets or error logs, it's very hard to determine what the source of your problem is.  There's no way to know if your error is describing the cause of your problem or a symptom of the problem without more information.

I can only offer some suggestions:

My first thought is that you're using a deprecated method in your code somewhere, possibly "Append", which if that is the case, more than likely has an updated counterpart, but you'll have to check documentation regarding that.

If you've used "Append" previously with no errors, then you should look into what exactly you've changed in your new build, and verify that the methods you're using are supported.

If your errors are vague or unhelpful, you can begin the process of elimination and start commenting out blocks of code until it builds successfully, and narrow down the source of the problem significantly.

However, it would be to your benefit to expand your question with more information.